# Hiding password in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to mask a password in my Jenkins build.

I have been trying [the mask-passwords plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin?showComments=true&showCommentArea=true#addcomment).

However, this doesn't seem to work with my Jenkins pipeline script, because if I define the password `PASSWD1` and then I use it in the script like this `${PASSWD1}`, I am getting:

```
No such DSL method '$' found among steps [addToClasspath, ansiColor, ansiblePlaybook, ....]
```

If I use `env.PASSWD1`, then its value will be resolved to `null`.

So how should I mask a password in a Jenkins pipeline script?

Comment: Can you show more of your Pipeline script? The `${PASSWD1}` syntax only works within a double-quoted string. Or you should likely be using the `PASSWD1` `env.PASSWD1`. Though that's unrelated to the Mask Passwords Plugin. Though this issue sounds relevant: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41955

Comment: I also tried using `env.PASSWD1`. I updated my question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the [Credentials Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials).

There you can define different types of credential, whether it's a single password ("secret text"), or a file, or a username/password combination.  Plus other plugins can contribute other types of credentials.

When you create a credential (via the Credentials link on the main Jenkins page), make sure you set an "ID".  In the example below, I've called it `my-pass`.  If you don't set it, it will still work, Jenkins will allocate an opaque UUID for you instead.

In any case, you can easily generate the required syntax with the [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator).

```groovy
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'my-pass', variable: 'PW1')]) {
    echo "My password is '${PW1}'!"
}
```

This will make the password available in the given variable only within this block. If you attempt to print the password, like I do here, it will be masked.

Comment: Thank you! This works if I just try to print the password. However, I also make an API call: `httpRequest myUrl`. This prints ```HttpMode: GET
URL: myUrl```, and this time, in `myUrl`, the password is in plain text. Any idea how I could prevent this as well?

Comment: @octavian are you  using [HTTP Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin)?.  You can pass credentials in "Authorization" header (which get masked in the logs) inestead of URL.

Comment: So what if you want to pass multiple variables to the same stage?

Answer (score 21):

Looking at this issue, https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27392, you should be able to do the following:

```
node {
    wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: '123ADS', var: 'SECRET']]]) {
        echo env['SECRET'];
    }
}
```

However, if you look at the last comments in that issue it doesn't work, seems like a bug. However, if you know the secret and accidentally print int in the logs, the it is hidden, like this:

```
node {
        wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: '123ADS', var: 'SECRET']]]) {
        echo "123ADS";
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in workspace/pl
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] wrap
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
********
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // wrap
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Regarding the error you are getting, `No such DSL method '$' found among steps ...`, I'm just guessing but you are probably using `${VAR}` directly in the pipeline script, `${...}` is only relevant inside strings in groovy.

EDIT:
Or you can use the `Credentails Plugin` and pipeline step `withCredentials`:

```
// Credential d389273c-03a0-45af-a847-166092b77bda is set to a string secret in Jenkins config.
node {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'd389273c-03a0-45af-a847-166092b77bda', variable: 'SECRET')]) {
        bat """
if ["${SECRET}"] == ["123ASD"] echo "Equal!"
""";
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in workspace/pl
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
[pl] Running batch script

workspace/pl>if ["****"] == ["****"] echo "Equal!" 
"Equal!"
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Note that this plugin binds the variable directly to the closure and not the environment as the other, e.g. I can use the variable `SECRET` directly.

Comment: You are showing the password: `password: '123ADS'` in the script in the plain text as well, right?. I wouldn't want it in the script either. It should be stored somewhere in Jenkins, in some Credentials field, encrypted.

Comment: I think you can set system wide password with `Mask Passwords Plugin`, I just used it locally here for a single complete example

Comment: Since `env.PASSWD1` is resolved to `null`, wrapping my code with ```wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: '123ADS', var: 'SECRET']]]) {``` wouldn't work, right? I mean it still wouldn't be resolve, no?

Comment: Doh, right, my bad, you, might be able to use the `withCredentials` step. I'll see if I can fix an example.

Comment: Consider the situation where you have a password and need to send it via curl as base64. Then Jenkins won't consider the base64 as a password and won't hide its value. Or the situation where the build agent has a password injected into it via env variable. Perhaps its on a rotation and gets changed every 30 min. You don't want that one to appear either in the log. There needs to be a way to tell Jenkins that some random string is a password that needs to be hidden in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pass="123456"
maskPasswords(varPasswordPairs: [[password: "${pass}"]]){
  sh "echo password is: ${pass}"
}
```

output:

```
password is: **********
```

or used var:

```
def pass="123456"
maskPasswords(varPasswordPairs: [[var: 'pass']]){
  sh "echo password is: ${pass}"
}
```