# Jenkins pipeline - pass Mask Passwords - Global name/password pairs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In jenkins pipeline project, I'm trying to pass Global name/password pairs to .sh script. 
note that I've already tried passing "${env.MyCred}"; $MyCred; withCredentials - yet failed.

I do know that in other type of jenkins projects, one need to check the "Mask passwords and regexes (and enable global passwords)" in order to be able use them. Pipeline project miss this configuration ..

Any idea how? Is there something I'm missing here ?

THX - albert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding password in Jenkins pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371909/hiding-password-in-jenkins-pipeline-script)

Comment: @ mkobit - Works as shown!! Thx for prompt and professional response