# Encrypting ansible vault-password-file

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-16.04, hashicorp-vault, ansible-vault

can we able to encrypt ansible vault-password-file too? cause the vault password will be exposed to some hackers if we placed in a password file? is there any way to provide security to the vault-password-file

Answer (score 0):

Use `ask-vault-pass` for manual launch.

You can use a script for build temporary vault-password-file with password stored in a security solution (vault by hashicorp).

Or you can use AWX or ansible tower for manage ansible-playbook.

Comment: but when we try with the jenkins, its not possible to go with ask-vault-pass because in the build process that will not ask for the password in the middle.

Comment: We don't use jendkins but i see this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371909/hiding-password-in-jenkins-pipeline-script  for provide protected password file in pipeline. We use the same process with gilab-ci.