# How to mask variable in Jenkins console[Groovy]

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How can I make groovy on Jenkins mask
**My groovy code:**

```
sh "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarurl:9000 -Dsonar.login=squ_a1111"
```

**Jenkins Console:**

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarurl:9000 -Dsonar.login=squ_a1111
```

When I run it, the **token** appears in the console, but I don't want it to appear. How can I do masking?

I want it this way, For example:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarurl:9000 -Dsonar.login=******
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed **Mask Passwords** Plugin in Jenkins and used it as follows.
Masking done

```
def token = "squ_a1111"
wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: token]]]) {
    sh "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarurl:9000 -Dsonar.login=${token}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use the **[Credentials Binding plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/#documentation)**.

There you can define different types of credentials, whether it's a single password ("secret text"), or a file, or a username/password combination.

Once defined, you can use it like so:

```
steps {
    withCredentials([
        string(credentialsId: "sonar-creds", variable: 'PWD_SONAR')
    ]) {
        script {
            sh "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarurl:9000 -Dsonar.login=$PWD_SONAR"
        }
    }
}
```

This will make the password available in the given variable only within this block. If you attempt to print the password, it will be masked.

### See also:

- [Bind credentials to variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)
- [Hiding password in Jenkins pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371909/hiding-password-in-jenkins-pipeline-script)

Comment: Thanks for help, I tried before but It didnt work and I dont have Username and Password, I just have only token. I solved the problem by installing the Mask Passwords plugin. I'll put it as a comment.

Comment: That works as well. I've edited my answer afterwards to only use a _string_ instead of a username-password pair. Both answers are valid :)